# Could candy crush in-app purchases gross revenue keep over a million children fed in africa?

Tags: economics, society

Discussing the mobile app in-app-purchase model, candy crush came up, and someone said the gross revenue of that app family alone could keep over one million children fed in africa.

Some googling around I found some references:

1. The cost of feeding a child supposedly is "[a little over $1 a day](https://www.erdo.ca/home-at-a-glance)" (USD$ or CAD$ ??)
           <sub>don't trust data that came from a 5 min google search</sub>

But I could not find any reliable data on CC daily earnings. It could be over a million dollars, so the claim has some basis.

So, skeptics:

---

**Is the sum of gross revenue of all the candy crush over all mobile platforms enough to feed a million children in africa?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

King brought in $1.33 billion in revenue from its "Candy Crush Saga" property alone in [calendar year 2014](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/feb/13/candy-crush-saga-players-855m-2014).  If we were to divide this out daily to 1 million children in Africa, that would be approximately $3.64 per child per day (($1.33billion/1million)/365days).

The cost to feed a child in Africa seems to vary wildly from source to source, searching yielded results from $1 down to $0.19 depending on the charity.  A 2009 study found that African schoolchildren across multiple countries were fed on the equivalent of [$40/year](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19689096) (standardized at feeding a 700 Calorie meal 200 days of the year), which works out to $0.20 per day ($40/200days).  Since this is only one meal of the day, we can assume it would cost $0.60 to feed a child al three meals.  Thus the $1 estimate in your source is higher than expected (but could cover more varied food and administrative costs).

Either way, the above translating King's revenue for a million children ($3.64 per day) is greater than that calculated costs of a full meal by a factor of 6.  So it is within reason that King's yearly revenue could feed a million Africa yearly, if not more.

Comment: I'm split about this answer. Normally, self-made calculations are frowned upon on this site. However, this is the type of really simple math that would be okay in an answer. I really don't know what to think of it!

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: @ThalesPereira so long the sources are real, trusteable and the calculations can be reproduced/verified, it is fine. **IF** you are worrying about the assumptions he took, he is assuming a bigger cost than the source explains. within the scope of the question, the answer is great.

Comment: @Mindwin Yeah, you're probably right. I did threw in a upvote a while ago (I liked the answer), I'm just nor sure about it's fitness. I'm not saying it's wrong - I would be happy this one could stay along.

Comment: @ThalesPereira my claim is not notable enough, but I got a satisfatory answer.

Comment: @Thales Pereria For what its worth, almost all of my calculations are unit conversions and not formulas of my choosing (years to days mostly).  Even going from one meal a day in the study to three meals a day was primarily a unit conversion (700 Calories x 3 = 2,100 Calories which is greater than the recommended 2,000 Calorie diet).  I could definitely see someone taking issue with that assumption (specifically if the meal in the study is indicative of 1/3 of daily nutritional needs, or heavily favors one aspect over another) though, even if the daily revenue is still 6x the average day.

Comment: I'll have to mark this as theoretical. While I have no issue with the calculations themselves, this relies on the assumption we can simply "scale up" existing charities. We can't assume this is a good approximation...